# clipboard content does not refresh during test

Tags: java, automated-tests, clipboard

I'm using webdriver with java and I want to test buttons which copy content from other text field. I have created a method to return content of clipboard:

```
    private String getClipboardContents() throws Exception {
    java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable contents=clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText=(contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if (hasTransferableText) {
        return (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which, I believe, works fine.
When I copy content to variable and after that change value of text field, click again button to copy content from clipboard  I'm getting the same content of clipboard from getClipboardContents(). I don't know why content does not refresh and stay the same, I tried even to clear clipboard in the middle of first and second pushing of button but I was getting null for second content.

Fragment of my test:

```
    @Test
public void checkClipboardForCopy() {

    String cFirstContent = null;
    String cSecondContent = null;
    IIDG idGenTab = goToIdG();
    idGT.getRadioButton().click();
    idGT.getButton().click();
    browser.wait.until(loadingMarkerGone());
    browser.findElement(By.id("IDClip")).click();
    try {
        cFirstContent = getClipboardContents();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String firstValue = idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value") ;
    verifyThat("Value of clipboard", cFirstContent, not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
    verifyThat("Value of id", idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value"), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
    verifyThat("Compare value of first clipboard content to attribute value", cFirstContent, equalTo(idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value")));
   // clearClipboardContent();
    idGT.getButton().click();
    browser.wait.until(loadingMarkerGone());
    browser.findElement(By.id("IDClip")).click();
    try {
        cSecondContent = getClipboardContents();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String secondValue = idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value") ;
    verifyThat("Value of clipboard", cSecondContent, not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
    verifyThat("Value of id", idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value"), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
    verifyThat("Compare value of second clipboard content to attribute value", cSecondContent, equalTo(idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value")));
    verifyThat("Compare value of first and second clipboard contents", cSecondContent, greaterThan(cFirstContent));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end code was not an issue, but time. 
I don't know why it worked for first click on button to copy clipboard content and for second didn't. 
I have added a simple sleep just after click on button event and it works just fine now, e.g:

```
 @Test 
public void checkClipboardForCopy() {

String cFirstContent = null;
String cSecondContent = null;
IIDG idGenTab = goToIdG();
idGT.getRadioButton().click();
idGT.getButton().click();
browser.wait.until(loadingMarkerGone());
browser.findElement(By.id("IDClip")).click();
try {
   Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
    }   
try {
    cFirstContent = getClipboardContents();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String firstValue = idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value") ;
verifyThat("Value of clipboard", cFirstContent, not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
verifyThat("Value of id", idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value"), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
verifyThat("Compare value of first clipboard content to attribute value", cFirstContent, equalTo(idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value")));
idGT.getButton().click();
browser.wait.until(loadingMarkerGone());
browser.findElement(By.id("IDClip")).click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
    }
try {
    cSecondContent = getClipboardContents();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String secondValue = idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value") ;
verifyThat("Value of clipboard", cSecondContent, not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
verifyThat("Value of id", idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value"), not(isEmptyOrNullString()));
verifyThat("Compare value of second clipboard content to attribute value", cSecondContent, equalTo(idGT.getNewId().getAttribute("value")));
verifyThat("Compare value of first and second clipboard contents", cSecondContent, greaterThan(cFirstContent));  
}
```